# How to wrap text in a cell in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice

How can I wrap text in a single cell in LibreOffice Calc??

Comment: Here's how to add a shortcut button to toggle "Wrap text automatically" on and off: https://askubuntu.com/a/1006919/327339

Answer (score 64, accepted):

An image is worth a thousand words… so I got 2 thousand words (Plus change) right here:

1. Select in the Menu: *Format → Cells…*

   [image]
2. Select in the *Format Cells* window: *Alignment Tab*

   [image]
3. Select *Wrap Text Automatically* from the *Properties* section.

   The end result will be something similar to this:

   [image]

Note that, at least up to LibreOffice 4.0, this option only works on cells that I written in **after** the option is activated. It will not automatically wrap cells created before.<sup>1</sup> See the following image:

[image]

The cell above was written before the option was activated. The bottom cell was written after the option was activated.

---

<sup>1</sup> For those wanting to wrap all of their already existing cells in a spreadsheet, simply execute <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, following by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and finally <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: I use a dutch version so I could not make nice images :( Can you check if when you set this BEFORE typing it changes wrap? Mine did not...

Comment: Mine does not either. For what I can see (Even on LibreOffice 4.0) is that it takes effect on newly written cells. Not one already created ones. Will make an image of this.

Comment: Thanks...that did the magic. :) Do you know if there is a way to add that to the toolbar instead of accessing it all the time thru the menu?

Comment: @Elysium You can select all the cells then apply the above option to do them all at once.

Comment: What if I want to wrap text but I do not want cell height to change automatically?

Comment: @Trismegistos How would you show the content without changing the height? The only other would be changing the row.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado You can show the content by clicking on it. Yust try to wrap then shrink manualy then double click.

Comment: Here's how to add a shortcut button to toggle "Wrap text automatically" on and off: https://askubuntu.com/a/1006919/327339

Comment: I had initially missed that this applies to the selected cell(s). This is ideal.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Format` > `Cells` > `Alignment` to have a variety of effects including `Wrap text automatically`.
Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to have more than one line of text per cell if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

> Manually

Type control + enter from inside a cell.

> Automatically

Seems bugged if you set it before editing the cell: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=57519

Setting the 'wrap' from a column or field in the tab 'alignment' works but you need to do this after inserting text.

Answer (score 2):

Select the cell, follow the path "Format\Cells\Allignment" and mark "Wrap text automatically".

Comment: There isnt such a "wrap text automatical" option there.

Comment: @Elysium The option is "Wrap text automatically." It appears near the bottom off the window. Make sure the Alignment tab is up.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/wrap-unwrap-insert-copied-row-or-column-and-paste-value/releases/1.0.1) extension for calc create a toolbar which has button for wrap text in selected cell(s), unwrap text in selected cell(s), insert copied row(s) or cell(s), insert copied column(s)or cell(s) and paste value

http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/wrap-unwrap-insert-copied-row-or-column-and-paste-value/releases/1.0.1

Answer (score 1):

In case of an imported xlsx file (but I not sure whether the file being xlsx-format is the point), the Wrap Text Automatically simply did not work, until I checked "Optimal Height" in Format/Row/.

Answer (score 1):

### Here's how to add a shortcut icon to toggle "Wrap text automatically" on and off:

Doing it [one time through the Format Cells menu is great and all](https://askubuntu.com/a/272232/327339), but I use this operation all the time. **Let's add a shortcut button, shall we?**

Click `View` --> `Toolbars` --> `Customize`.
In the `Toolbar` drop down select `Formatting`. Now in the `Toolbar Content` section scroll down and click on `Justified`, since I want to add my cell wrap icon just after that one.

Click `Add`, then choose `Format` from the "Category" menu and `Automatic Row Break` from the "Commands" menu. Here's what those menus look like:

[image]

Click `Add` then `Close`.

Now click on `Modify` --> `Change Icon...` and choose an icon you think looks half-way decent. I chose this one:
[image]

when done, click `Ok` as necessary to exit the menus, then click on `View` --> `Toolbars` and ensure the "Formatting" toolbar we just added the icon to is visible. It will have a check mark next to it to indicate it is visible.

Here's what my icons look like now:

[image]

Focus in on this area:
[image]

Here's the icon I just added right after the "Justify" icon.
[image]

**Select a cell and click this icon to toggle "Automatic Row Break" (ie: "Wrap text automatically") on and off**, just like you can do in Microsoft Excel!

*Demo'ed in LibreOffice 4.2.8.2, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.*

Answer (score 0):

Cell wrapping by "Format->Cells->Allignment->Wrap text automatically" makes it wrap horizontally. 
To Wrap it completely, You need to select the cell or all the rows and select "Optimal Row Height" which will automatically increases the row height according to the text within...

Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can make out, you select wherever you want text wrapped, a cell, row, column, or the whole page or document, then click the "wrap" button on the toolbar. It's next to the three "align" buttons. You may now find at least two "sub issues".
The cell and all cells in that row have been extended vertically to hold all the text. The solution is to force the row height back to the same as all the others by Format>Rows>Height and select required height or the default.
Now you may find that when you narrow the column width only the bottom row oftext is displayed, that is, the last word or two and a blank to the end of the line. You probably want to see the first few words, so go to the Align (Top) button on the toolbar.
If you don't see what you want on the toolbar you have to go
Select required>Format>Cells and in the window select the Align tab and work from there, where you can align and also select wrap in the properties section.